# Creating NSURL with custom query parameter returns nil

Tags: url, nsurl

I have a UISearchBar from which I'm extracting the text that represents an address and building from it a JSON URL for Google Geocoder.

```
NSString* address = searchbar.text;
NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false", address];
```

If I copy & paste the url from debug window to the browser it works like a charm but when I try to convert it to NSURL i get `nil`

```
NSURL* theUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your url seems fine, try using NSMutableRequest and changing the http headers with a different user agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the encoding to the address prior to concatenating the url and that fixed the problem so now the code looks like this:

```
NSString* address = searchbar.text;
NSString *encodedString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, CFBridgingRetain(address), NULL, (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]", kCFStringEncodingUTF8));

NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false", encodedString];
```